# hibernate configuration windows authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2012

I am trying to configure hibernate with windows authentication.

I wrote the following code:

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/db_name;integratedSecurity=true</property>           
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
<property name="connection.username"></property>
<property name="connection.password"></property>
```

I received the following error message:

> "The login failed for user sa..."

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Your connection string uses integrated security, so you use Windows authentication. How on the earth did you get the error for login "sa"?

Comment: Who and where did pass "sa"?

Comment: I resolved...There was an error int the configuration :)!!!Thanks